# JavaScript - Variable not resetting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have some trouble with my JavaScript. This script uses Ajax GET to retrieve content from a PHP page. And it gets the content depending on a variable called `count`.

This code works until it gets to the last item in my database. When it gets `no_data` from the PHP page: It should reset the `counter` variable and start over from the top, and continue in a infinite loop. But when i try to reset the variable with `count = 0;`: Nothing happens. Why is that?

**Here is my JS code:**

```
var count = 0;
var timer;

$(window).load(function() {

    load_new_entry();

//  timer = window.setInterval(load_new_entry, 7500);
//  window.clearTimeout(timer);
});

function load_new_entry() {
    fade_out();
}

function fade_out() {
    $(".container").fadeOut(1500, load_data);
    window.clearTimeout(timer);
}

function fade_in() {
    $(".container").fadeIn(1500);
    timer = window.setInterval(load_new_entry, 7500);
}

function load_data() {
    getDetails(count);
    count++;
}

function getDetails(count) {
    $.get("data.php?count="+count,function(data,status){

        if (data != 'no_data') {

            var jsonReturnData = $.parseJSON(data);
            $(".container").html(jsonReturnData.content);
            fade_in();

            //console.log("Load details: " + count);

        } else {
            count = 1;
            fade_in();
            //console.log("Counter Reset: " + count);
        }

    });
}
```

**And here is my PHP:**

```
<?php

mysql_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("infoscreen");

function grab_data($count) {
    $get_data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM display ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT ".$count.",1");
    while ($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_data)) {

        $id = $data['id'];
        $content = $data['content'];

        $return_data = array('id' => $id, 'content' => $content);

        //echo  $return_data['content'];
        echo json_encode($return_data);
    }
}

if (isset($_GET['count'])) {
    $count = $_GET['count'];

    $utf_8 = mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

    $data_exists = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM display ORDER BY id ASC");
    if (mysql_num_rows($data_exists) > $count) {
        // Next record is available
        grab_data($count);
    } else {
        // Next record is not available
        echo "no_data";
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `count` as parameter. Replace `getDetails(count)` with `getDetails()`

Comment: @Satpal Oh silly me! Fixed it! Post it as an answer and ill accept it. So you get your points

Comment: Oh, i just saw it, mark he's answer as the right when he post it...

Comment: @DJZorrow, Glab I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have defined parameter as `Global`. You don't need to pass it as a parameter. When you declares parameter with same name. It will hide global parameter.

Thus, don't use `count` as parameter. i.e replace `getDetails(count)` with `getDetails()`